# Exception after version upgrade

Tags: java, optaplanner

Having problem with Score persistance on a project using Optaplanner v7.11.0.Final, I upgraded to the latest one (v7.25.0.Final) but got the following exception :

```
The externalObject (Etat(super=DbObject(id=11), libelle=RCD, ordre=60)) with planningId ((class plr.domain.Etat$HibernateProxy$EZnO4cSz,11)) has no known workingObject (null).
Maybe the workingObject was never added because the planning solution doesn't have a @ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotation on a member with instances of the externalObject's class (class plr.domain.Etat$HibernateProxy$EZnO4cSz).
```

I finally found that the exception does not appear when upgrading up to v7.17.0.Final.

What have been done in since v7.18.0.Final that makes the code failing ?

How to fix it ?

EDIT : 
For more information, here are the relative classes

```java
package org.optaplanner.plr.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.lookup.PlanningId;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public class Etat extends DbObject {

    @Column
    private String libelle;

    @Column
    private int ordre;

    @Override
    @PlanningId
    public Integer getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

and its superclass

```java
package org.optaplanner.plr.domain;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public abstract class DbObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
}
```

and finally, the simplest config ever :)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
    <!-- To solve faster by saturating multiple CPU cores -->
    <moveThreadCount>4</moveThreadCount>
    <solutionClass>org.optaplanner.plr.domain.PlannifSolution</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>org.optaplanner.plr.domain.Plannif</entityClass>
    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <scoreDrl>org/optaplanner/plr/solver/score.drl</scoreDrl>
        <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>
    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>1200</secondsSpentLimit>
        <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>300</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>
</solver>
```

The whole trace is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:763)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at org.optaplanner.plr.Application.main(Application.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (2) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:142)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:187)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:157)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:70)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:88)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:191)
    at org.optaplanner.plr.Application$1.run(Application.java:222)
    at org.optaplanner.plr.Application$1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7557a0d1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at org.optaplanner.plr.Application$1$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c098b4dc.run(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The externalObject (Etat(super=DbObject(id=11), libelle=RCD, ordre=60)) with planningId ((class org.optaplanner.plr.domain.Etat$HibernateProxy$YghGFDSA,11)) has no known workingObject (null).
Maybe the workingObject was never added because the planning solution doesn't have a @ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotation on a member with instances of the externalObject's class (class org.optaplanner.plr.domain.Etat$HibernateProxy$YghGFDSA).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.lookUpWorkingObject(PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.java:66)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.LookUpManager.lookUpWorkingObject(LookUpManager.java:75)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(AbstractScoreDirector.java:509)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove.rebase(ChangeMove.java:85)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove.rebase(ChangeMove.java:33)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I think it was introduced here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/477/files#diff-9bf72aecca4eeb82f25f145a6aae7019 but it was released in 7.19.0, not in 7.18.0. The change seems like a good fail-fast mechanism that may be detecting a problem with your code. Can you post the `Etat` class and maybe its ancestor? I'd like to see how you use the `@PlanningId` annotation.

Comment: _@PlanningId_ is put on the accessor as _Id_ comes from the superclass and is the same as the one generated from the database. When putting the annotation on the id field of the _DbObject_ class only, the solver simply doesn't work

Comment: Thanks that's very useful. I need one more piece of information to investigate this - the exception stack trace. I guess this doesn't happen in a problem fact change but in the first move of the LS phase and you're using multithreaded solving - to be sure, please share you solver config XML as well.

Comment: Absolutely, after construction, which takes four or five steps, LocalSearch immediately fails

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Geoffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472109/geoffrey-de-smet) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57848870/1677089) and [yurloc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691152/yurloc) comments, I finally found what was the problem.

First, `Etat` objects were coming through a join with another object. Changing the `ManyToOne` fetch type to `Eager` instead of `Lazy` showed that I got the same exception but with `Etat` objects instead of their Hibernate proxies.

So it means that these objects were not know by Optaplanner. Indeed, I was using a specific range per planning variable for `Etat` but never load all these ones in the problem facts.

In the end, it has nothing to do with detached vs attached objects and the join fetch type can be put back to `Lazy` value.

Answer (score 1):

My theory:

Your code already had a bug, but in 7.11, OptaPlanner didn't detect it and didn't fail-fast. Starting from 7.18, it does detect and fail-fast, to *help you*...

As far as I can tell without the stacktrace, a method like `ScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject()` fails fast, probably in a callback given to `addProblemFactChange()` or in multithreaded solving. In any case, it can't find the working entity based upon the planningId of that entity.

**Notice how error message says the planningId (usually a `Long`, `String`, `UUID`) is an instance of class `plr.domain.Etat$HibernateProxy$EZnO4cSz`. That countradicts your domain model in your question, which says it's an Integer. Put a breakpoint where the message is thrown and validate this please.**

Potential causes:
 - mixing in attached JPA objects in general - which I would doubt
 - mixing in attached JPA objects and using OptaPlanner's @PlanningId annotation on a method that doesn't have the JPA @Id annotation, causing JPA to proxy that method.

Either way, detaching the JPA objects before working with them in OptaPlanner will fix it. Please confirm if that fixes it, so I can add a "Maybe detach your JPA objects" in the error message.

Comment: I confirm that where the message is thrown, I get a proxy instead of the real object. What I don't understand is why it was working in 7.11 with other facts that which are using the same pattern (i.e. subclasses of DbObject)

Comment: I changed the relation fetching the Etat from Lazy to Eager and still get the error but this time on Etat directly. So I think I forgot to add some Etat to the whole solution :)