# Array out of bounds exception when persisting score

Tags: java, optaplanner

Using Optaplanner v7.17.0.Final, when saving the score, I get the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.optaplanner.persistence.jpa.impl.score.AbstractScoreHibernateType.getPropertyValue(AbstractScoreHibernateType.java:108)
```

My *PlanningSolution* class contains the following JPA description:

```java
        @PlanningScore
        @Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "initScore"), 
                             @Column(name = "hardScore"), 
                             @Column(name = "softScore") })
        private HardSoftScore score;
```

Which is what the documentation advices. Moreover, the following annotation is used on this class :

```java
@TypeDef(defaultForType = HardSoftScore.class, 
         typeClass = HardSoftScoreHibernateType.class) // Hibernate annotation
```

Debugging the Optaplanner code, at the provided line, the *levelNumbers* local variable contains only 2 level numbers (hard and soft) whereas the call is to the index 2.

Of course, removing the *initScore* column lead to a mapping exception as the *HardSoftScoreHibernateType* declares 3.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Isn't this the bug that Musa fixed over the summer in optaplanner-persistence-jpa? Try the latest version please - let us know if it still occurs with that version.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to fix when upgrading :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806094/exception-after-version-upgrade

Comment: As soon as I'll be able to upgrade, I'll tell you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by upgrading to the latest version (v7.25.0.Final) of OptaPlanner.